# PowerShell and checking local administrator rights

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm building a PowerShell script that requires local administrator rights on the server it's run on and I would need to check that the user has those rights.

The problem is that the user might not be directly in the local Administrators group, but in a domain group that's in the local group and has the permissions that way. Then again the local Administrators group might have several domain groups as members.

Is there a way to "simply" check whether the user has local admin rights or not without going through Get-ADGroupMember for all the nested domain groups in Administrators or so?

*edit:* For example, one option could be a simple command that returns "Access denied" if the user is not local admin, but such a command that would be "safe" to execute just for this purpose.

Comment: I was trying to find the sid information to see if I could compare it to that of the local computer. In your edit it seems like you are just looking for a check. Easiest one I could think of is try to write to the root of the main partition - C:\

Answer (score 3):

I found this approach, which is quite lovely, on [Garrett Serack's Git repository](https://gist.github.com/fearthecowboy/0781e8914ad9b3a1b104).

```
 If ( ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{"You're a wizard Harry!"
#DoAdminThingsHere
}
ELSE{"Not an Admin!"}
```

Seems to get the job done.  It determines the current permission level of the user using .net types.

Comment: This seems to work, yes, but how can I specify it to check the permissions of user X when you're running it as user Y?

Comment: This is actually a much harder question to answer then.  A user could obtain local admin rights through a number of ways, and the best way to determine is a certain user has local admin on a certain system would be to go the AD route.

Comment: I tried creating a temp file in C:\ with New-Item and mapping C:\ with New-PSDrive but neither one of the commands support -Credential parameter with PS v2.0 (which I'm limited to work with in this scenario). Any alternatives for those at hand..?

Comment: If you're testing for admin rights when the script runs on the user's computer, I think you could use this approach I've given here.  If you look at the full code using the link I've provided, the script Garrett made can actually detect if the user is not running PowerShell as an admin, the relaunch with administrative perms.

Comment: I couldn't figure this out and eventually went another way with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/23/you-don-t-have-to-be-an-administrator-to-run-remote-powershell-commands.aspx -- Giving 'Execute' permissions to user X circumvents the whole original issue.